# How to add source_security_group_id in Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Hi I am trying to create security group in AWS CDK. when I try to create Ingress rule, I want to specify source_security_group_id. I created security group as below.

```
mws_vpc_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(self,"securitygroupname",
        description="EC2 Services Security Group",
        security_group_name="securitygroupname",
        vpc=vpc
        );
```

Then I want to add ingress rules as below.

```
 SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "80"
          ToPort: "80"
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
```

Can someone help me to write same template using aws cdk?

Comment: Can you comment as to whether the advice worked? Other people coming to the site will want to know how to fix the problem also

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there's a method belonging to `ec2.SecurityGroup` called `add_ingress_rule` which takes a "Peer" and a "Connection" as arguments. These being another Security Group and a Port

So you can try something like this

```
my_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "securitygroupone",
  description="EC2 Services Security Group",
  security_group_name="securitygroupone",
  vpc=vpc
)

my_sg_two = ec2.SecurityGroup(self, "securitygrouptwo",
  description="EC2 Services Security Group with Ingress from securitygroupone",
  security_group_name="securitygrouptwo",
  vpc=vpc
)

my_sg_two.add_ingress_rule(my_sg, 8080)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/SecurityGroup.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.add_ingress_rule